# Add to array, check if id exists and randomly change it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying different ways for a while and I've reached that point where whatever I do just gets wrong.

So this is what I've tried to do. First I create a random number and add it to an array:

```
for(.......){
  random[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length));
```

Then another random number is added to the array:

```
randomkey[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length));
```

Then I create this function:

```
var accept=true;
// word is a text (length:22)
function acceptRandom(random,word){
  stop:
    for(var i=0;i<randomkey.length+1; i++){
      if(word[i] != word[random])
        accept = true;
      else {
        accept = false;
        break stop;
      }
    }
    if(accept == false){
      newrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length));
      // Random number exists so we call the function again with a new value
      acceptRandom(newrandom,word);
    } else
      return random;
}
```

Now, the problem is that it won't return the new value when the random number already exists.

Comment: I would but haven't gotten any answers to the questions so eventually I solved them by myself and mentionde in my post that i've solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're iterating through the whole list, there will **always** be a point where `word[i] == word[random]` (because you've comparing the word to itself.)  A quick fix would be:

```
for(var i=0;i<randomkey.length+1; i++){
    if(word[i] == word[random] && i !== random) {
        accept = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

You'll also need to return your recursive call:

```
if(accept == false){
      newrandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length));
      // Random number exists so we call the function again with a new value
      return acceptRandom(newrandom,word);
}
```

Honestly, I think you've run into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What exactly are you trying to do here?  There's probably a better way.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the XY problem. So, i've tried what you mentioned and get the same result: it doesn't return the value if it already exists that means when accept = false;

Comment: return acceptRandom(newrandom,word); solved the return problem, but there are still a bug , i'm going to check it up and i'll be back if i solved it or not

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for(.......){
  random[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length));
// You're assigning a random number to random[i]
```

to

```
for(.......){
  random[i] = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * (word.length))];
// Whereas you should be assigning words[random number] to random[i]
```

Comment: Actually in this case I want to assign a random number to random[i]